# Ubuntu 23.10 wont wake up after closing the lid on my 2017 MacBook Pro

Tags: suspend, macbook, 23.10

I recently replaced MacOS Ventura with Ubuntu 23.10 on my 2017 MacBook Pro and every time I close then re-open the lid it wont wake up. I end up having to hard restart the laptop to use it.